# How to access the T object of a Task<T>

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I am using an async method synchronously using the Task.Wait() method, but when the call is complete I would like to access to the object templated by the Task<>.

```
Task<HttpResponseMessage> message = _httpClient.GetAsync(Globals.ENDPOINT_URI + Uri.EscapeDataString(query));
message.Wait();
```

How do I access the HttpResponseMessage of the message object ?

Thank you

Comment: `message.Result`

Comment: you could also use `var message`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get result from async method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884604/get-result-from-async-method) or [How to get returned value of async Task<string> methdoName()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26269066/how-to-get-returned-value-of-async-taskstring-methdoname)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to use `async/await`, as it's considered a bad practice to use `Wait` and `Result`. Your code would be updated to the following:

```
HttpResponseMessage message =
    await _httpClient.GetAsync(Globals.ENDPOINT_URI + Uri.EscapeDataString(query));
```

`await` will both wait for the call to complete and provide the result, which will sit in your `message` variable.

There are plenty of good resources on the Internet and great answers here on Stack Overflow regarding `async/await`, introduced in C# 5. Here's one page to get you started: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async.

EDIT: Here's a good resource on the `Result` problem: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html